# Node & React - npm start - is running BUT localhost:3000 "cant be reached"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, lerna, npm-start

(having node version 12 and npm version 6)

- Backend: Node.js
- Front: React.js
  i cloned repository
  cd into the directory
  ran

`npm install (installing dependencies etc...)`

and when i ran

```
npm start
```

and i get

```
[Ben@Mac:~/Desktop/test]$ npm start

> answers-entry-level-exam@1.0.0 start /Users/Ben/Desktop/test
> lerna run start --parallel

lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "npm run start"
@ans-exam/server: > @ans-exam/server@1.0.0 start 
/Users/Ben/Desktop/test/server
@ans-exam/server: > ts-node-dev index.ts
@ans-exam/server: Using ts-node version 8.5.2, typescript version 3.7.2
@ans-exam/server: server running 3232
```

- which seems like the server is running okay
- but localhost:3000 cant be reached
  not opening anything
  **the first time it did open and there was a MacOS popup on the right side of the screen related to node ( i think that is the issue but cant figure out how to fix)**

my package.json:

```
{
 "name": "answers-entry-level-exam",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "b": "npm run bootstrap",
 "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 "start": "lerna run start --parallel",
 "postinstall": "npm run bootstrap"
},
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
 "lerna": "^3.22.1"
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using no framework change your port directly in your code. Otherwise if you are using a framework like ExpressJS try to set a variable PORT=3000 in your terminal. On the other side there could be a possibility that you've not closed a previous application running and your OS is using that port already (which is weird because it should be showned in your terminal aswell).

Comment: the framework is Express that running on port 3232 (that is the Backend)        for example localhost:3232/api/tickets work fine but Front not uploading

Comment: which repo did you clone for the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

I cloned again the repo and it fixed that
Cheers to all those who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost:3232. I see in your output `server running 3232`

Comment: that is the port of the backend (Node) if I'm not mistaken